# Error loading obj THREE js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load a .obj file to my project using Threejs and I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: geometry.computeCentroids is not a function
at THREE.OBJLoader.parse (OBJLoader.js:304)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (OBJLoader.js:22)
```

I've been searching for a solution, but I didn't find anything. Does someone have a clue?

Obs: I would like to post my code here, but I'm not allowed by stackoverflow.

Comment: Your version is 3+ years old. Upgrade to the current version of three.js and the current version of `OBJLoader.js` or `OBJLoader2.js`.

Comment: I looked for a new version and worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by WestLangley in comments.

---

> Your version is 3+ years old. Upgrade to the current version of
>   three.js and the current version of `OBJLoader.js` or `OBJLoader2.js`. –
>   WestLangley 14 hours ago

Thank you.